# Export all posts as individual plain txt files

Tags: export, text

I wish to export all of my posts as individual plain text files. So, the format may be something like:

```
title.txt
```

```
Title: title
Pub date: date
Category: cat

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
```

Is this possible? Is there a plugin or workaround to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just work with the default XML export? One could conceivably write a script that breaks the XML down into individual posts (though such a solution would be off-topic for WPSE), which might be easier than writing a Plugin/custom exporter?

Comment: @samiles: It looks very much as if you wanted to switch to a static blog generator like Jekyll. I suppose you already know [this article](http://vitobotta.com/how-to-migrate-from-wordpress-to-jekyll/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this (you may need to bootstrap WP by loading `wp-load.php`, depending on where you put this code).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    //'posts_per_page' => -1 //uncomment this to get all posts
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $f = fopen(get_the_title() . '.txt', 'w');
    $content = 'Title: ' . get_the_title() . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= 'Pub date: ' . get_the_date() . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= 'Category: ';
    foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) {
        $content .= $cat->cat_name . ', ';
    }       
    $content .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $content .= get_the_content();

    fwrite($f, $content);
    fclose($f);
endwhile;
```

Keep in mind, if two posts have the same title, you'll only get one text file.

Comment: Yall remember to check if the script has write permission for the directory you choose :-)

Answer (score 3):

A cursory search doesn't turn up any plugins that do this ... but you could use the built-in exporter as an example for building out your own plugin.  It's located in `/wp-admin/includes/export.php`.

Essentially, it's a PHP page that queries the database to get all of your posts, then dumps the content into a pre-build XML template that can be imported later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks very much as if you wanted to switch to a static blog generator like Jekyll. The following answer is based on pdb's answer and should be ready-to-use. My answer can deal with:

- multiple post with the same title
- German umlauts

Here it is:

```
<?
require_once('wp-load.php');

function getFeaturedImage($postid) {
    $featured_image = "";
    $array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
    if (count($array)>1) {
        $featured_image = $array[0];
        $featured_image = str_replace('http://martin-thoma.com/wp-content/uploads/', '', $featured_image);
    }
    return $featured_image;
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'posts_per_page' => -1 //uncomment this to get all posts
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
$i=0;
$titles = array();
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    $i++;
    $name = $post->post_name;
    if ($name == "") {
        $name = strtolower(get_the_title());
        $replacements = array(
            ' ' => '-',
            '#' => 'nr',
            '/' => 'or',
            'ö' => 'o',
            'ü' => 'u',
            'ä' => 'a',
            'ß' => 'ss'
        );
        $name = str_replace(array_keys($replacements), $replacements, $name);
    }

    if (array_key_exists($name, $titles)) {
        $name = $post->post_name."-".$post->ID;
    } else {
        $titles[$name] = true;
    }
    echo $name."<br/>";

    $f = fopen("export/".$name. '.md', 'w');
    $content = "---".PHP_EOL;
    $content.= "layout: post".PHP_EOL;
    $content.= "title: ".get_the_title().PHP_EOL;
    $content.= "author: ".get_the_author().PHP_EOL;
    $content.= "date: ".get_the_date('Y-m-d h:i:s').PHP_EOL;
    $content.= "categories: ".PHP_EOL;
    $cats = get_the_category();
    if ($cats) {
        foreach($cats as $category) {
            $content .= '- '.$category->name.PHP_EOL; 
        }
    }
    $content .= 'tags: ';
    $posttags = get_the_tags();

    if ($posttags) {
        $content .= PHP_EOL;
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $content.= "- ".$tag->name.PHP_EOL; 
        }
    } else {
        $content .= "[]".PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID));
    $content .= 'featured_image: '.getFeaturedImage($postid).PHP_EOL;
    $content .= '---'.PHP_EOL;    
    $content .= get_the_content();
    fwrite($f, $content);
    fclose($f);
endwhile;
echo $i." posts exported."
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

"Why not just work with the default XML export"

I don't have an answer, but the OP might want to do this so he or she can [import the posts into Devonthink Pro](http://www.stevenberlinjohnson.com/movabletype/archives/000230.html) or a similar program.

Comment: Hi jseliger - welcome to WPSE! Please post comments as comments rather than answer, thanks!

Comment: The URL is 404.