# How to export a list of all media urls?

Tags: plugins, media

How can I export the list of all media files' url, So I can use it in some other documents?

Answer (score 3):

You can get what you want via:

```
function get_the_file_urls( ) {
    $query_media_urls = array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    );

    $query_urls = new WP_Query( $query_media_urls );       

    foreach ( $query_urls->posts as $url ) {            
        echo '<ul>' . '<li>' . wp_get_attachment_url( $url->ID ) . '</li>' . '</ul>';
    }
}
```

This could either go to functions.php and then call it in a theme file via `get_the_file_urls();` or you could alternatively use a plugin that allows PHP code in the post/page content as a one-off to get your list and then do whatever you want with it..

**EDIT:** As per the suggestion of @Bram Vanroy, which was valid and more accurately described the original question by @M0HiT to a) give credit to @pbd who originally gave this very nice example, b) save some time and c) encourage self-learning, you may have a look [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53069/export-all-posts-as-individual-plain-txt-files) and combine my answer to that by @pbd.

Comment: Might be better to immediately export as txt, since TS wants to use it in other documents as well. This saves him or her the time to copy to a document.