# Make WordPress more like Jekyll (using wp-cli package?)

Tags: wp-cli

I'd like to create and edit WordPress posts on my local file system and then "push" them to my WordPress blog just as if I'd added them directly from WordPress' web interface.

Is there any way to do this, for example, a wp-cli package?

I am familar with the "WordPress to Jekyll Exporter" plugin, and have read [Export all posts as individual plain txt files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53069) but neither does quite what I'm looking for.

I'm thinking about writing one myself, but I'd prefer to use a well-tested existing tool.

I originally considered switching to Jekyll, but I still want WordPress' functionality including comments, trackbacks, server-side scripting, plug-ins, etc.

It would still be nice to use Jekyll's markup parser and other functionality, but, ultimately, I want to be running WordPress, not Jekyll.

Comment: I don't really get what system you want to use on your "local file system", but maybe the WP REST API would be worth a shot for you.

Comment: I give you a hint what you want and what to search. You want a flat-file CMS like Grav https://getgrav.org/ inside WordPress. Unfortunately I don't know any tool for this job.

Comment: @kuchenundkakao I'm pretty sure wp-cli is an interface to the WP REST API.